# C# Web Api Error StatusCode: 500

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

Buenas Estoy Desarrollando una Aplicacion que Consume un Servicio Web Api pero cuando lo Ejecuto Me sale Error **StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error'**

Este Es El Codigo de la Web Api

**La Conexion la Probe y Funciona.**

***Codigo C#***

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("~/api/SingCronizarcxc")]
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public IHttpActionResult SingCronizarcxc(List<CuentaPorCobrar> Cxcobrar)
    {


        string Command = "INSERT INTO cuentaporcobrar( Numero, Coddoc, Codclte, Cliente, Cedula, Telefono, Movil, Direccion, Referencia, Garante, GaranTetelefono, GaranteCedula, GaranteDireccion, Codprestamo, Cuota, FPago, Codmoneda, Divisa, Valor, Balance, Mora, Atraso, IdReg, Codcontrol, CodMod, Modalidad, RefCodoc, RefNumero, RefCuota, RefIdReg, RefCodcontrol, RefFmov, IdTransaccion, Longitud, Latitud, Comentario, EsSolicitud, LongitudPago, LatitudPago, FultimoPago, MontoUltimoPago, MontoAbono, MoraPagada, Interes, Capital, DiasAtraso, Imagen, Fecha) "
                         + " VALUES (@Numero,@Coddoc,@Codclte,@Cliente,@Cedula,@Telefono,@Movil,@Direccion,@Referencia,@Garante,@GaranTetelefono,@GaranteCedula,@GaranteDireccion,@Codprestamo,@Cuota,@FPago,@Codmoneda,@Divisa,@Valor,@Balance,@Mora,@Atraso,@IdReg,@Codcontrol,@CodMod,@Modalidad,@RefCodoc,@RefNumero,@RefCuota,@RefIdReg,@RefCodcontrol,@RefFmov,@IdTransaccion,@Longitud,@Latitud,@Comentario,@EsSolicitud,@LongitudPago,@LatitudPago,@FultimoPago,@MontoUltimoPago,@MontoAbono,@MoraPagada,@Interes,@Capital,@DiasAtraso,@Imagen,@Fecha)";
        foreach (var item in Cxcobrar)
        {
            if (Jarsoft.TipoConexion <= 1)
            {
                //Si la Conexion es a MySql
                if (!DataAcc.Conectar())
                {
                    return Ok(false);
                }

                MySqlConnection conn = DataAcc.Conn;
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(Command, conn);
                #region Parameters
                command.Parameters.Add("@Numero", MySqlDbType.VarChar,12);
                command.Parameters["@Numero"].Value=item.Numero;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Coddoc", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 2);
                command.Parameters["@Coddoc"].Value =item.Coddoc ;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Codclte", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 2);
                command.Parameters["@Codclte"].Value= item.Codclte ;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Cliente",   MySqlDbType.VarChar, 10);
                command.Parameters["@Cliente"].Value= item.Cliente ;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Cedula",   MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                command.Parameters["@Cedula"].Value = item.Cedula;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Telefono", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                command.Parameters["@Telefono"].Value= item.Telefono;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Movil", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                command.Parameters["@Movil"].Value= item.Movil ;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Direccion", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
                command.Parameters["@Direccion"].Value= item.Direccion ;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Referencia", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
                command.Parameters["@Referencia"].Value= item.Referencia;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Garante", MySqlDbType.VarChar,100);
                command.Parameters["@Garante"].Value= item.Garante ;
                command.Parameters.Add("@GaranTetelefono",  MySqlDbType.VarChar,50);
                command.Parameters["@GaranTetelefono"].Value = item.GaranTetelefono;
                command.Parameters.Add("@GaranteCedula",MySqlDbType.VarChar,50);
                command.Parameters["@GaranteCedula"].Value=  item.GaranteCedula ;
                command.Parameters.Add("@GaranteDireccion", MySqlDbType.VarChar,300);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Codprestamo", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 12);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Cuota", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 5);
                command.Parameters.Add("@FPago", MySqlDbType.Date);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Codmoneda", MySqlDbType.VarChar,5);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Divisa",  MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Valor", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Balance", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Mora", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Atraso", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@IdReg", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 36);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Codcontrol", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 36);
                command.Parameters.Add("@CodMod", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 5);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Modalidad", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                command.Parameters.Add("@RefCodoc", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 2);
                command.Parameters.Add("@RefNumero", MySqlDbType.VarChar,12);
                command.Parameters.Add("@RefCuota", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 5);
                command.Parameters.Add("@RefIdReg", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 36);
                command.Parameters.Add("@RefCodcontrol", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 36);
                command.Parameters.Add("@RefFmov", MySqlDbType.Date);
                command.Parameters.Add("@IdTransaccion", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 36);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Longitud", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Latitud", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Comentario", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
                command.Parameters.Add("@EsSolicitud", MySqlDbType.Bit);
                command.Parameters.Add("@LongitudPago", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@LatitudPago", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@FultimoPago", MySqlDbType.Date);
                command.Parameters.Add("@MontoUltimoPago", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@MontoAbono", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@MoraPagada", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Interes", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Capital", MySqlDbType.Double);
                command.Parameters.Add("@DiasAtraso", MySqlDbType.Int32);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Imagen", MySqlDbType.MediumBlob);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Fecha", MySqlDbType.Date);

                command.Parameters["@GaranteCedula"].Value = item.GaranteCedula;
                command.Parameters["@GaranteDireccion"].Value = item.GaranteDireccion;
                command.Parameters["@Codprestamo"].Value = item.Codprestamo;
                command.Parameters["@Cuota"].Value = item.Cuota;
                command.Parameters["@FPago"].Value = item.FPago;
                command.Parameters["@Codmoneda"].Value = item.Codmoneda;
                command.Parameters["@Divisa"].Value = item.Divisa;
                command.Parameters["@Valor"].Value = item.Valor;
                command.Parameters["@Balance"].Value = item.Balance;
                command.Parameters["@Mora"].Value = item.Mora;
                command.Parameters["@Atraso"].Value = item.Atraso;
                command.Parameters["@IdReg"].Value = item.IdReg;
                command.Parameters["@Codcontrol"].Value = item.Codcontrol;
                command.Parameters["@CodMod"].Value = item.CodMod;
                command.Parameters["@Modalidad"].Value = item.Modalidad;
                command.Parameters["@RefCodoc"].Value = item.RefCodoc;
                command.Parameters["@RefNumero"].Value = item.RefNumero;
                command.Parameters["@RefCuota"].Value = item.RefCuota;
                command.Parameters["@RefIdReg"].Value = item.RefIdReg;
                command.Parameters["@RefCodcontrol"].Value = item.RefCodcontrol;
                command.Parameters["@RefFmov"].Value = item.RefFmov;
                command.Parameters["@IdTransaccion"].Value = item.IdTransaccion;
                command.Parameters["@Longitud"].Value = item.Longitud;
                command.Parameters["@Latitud"].Value = item.Latitud;
                command.Parameters["@Comentario"].Value = item.Comentario;
                command.Parameters["@EsSolicitud"].Value = item.EsSolicitud;
                command.Parameters["@LongitudPago"].Value = item.LongitudPago;
                command.Parameters["@LatitudPago"].Value = item.LatitudPago;
                command.Parameters["@FultimoPago"].Value = item.FultimoPago;
                command.Parameters["@MontoUltimoPago"].Value = item.MontoUltimoPago;
                command.Parameters["@MontoAbono"].Value = item.MontoAbono;
                command.Parameters["@MoraPagada"].Value = item.MoraPagada;
                command.Parameters["@Interes"].Value = item.Interes;
                command.Parameters["@Capital"].Value = item.Capital;
                command.Parameters["@DiasAtraso"].Value = item.DiasAtraso;
                command.Parameters["@Imagen"].Value = item.Imagen;
                command.Parameters["@Fecha"].Value = item.Fecha;

                #endregion



                //Ejecutar el Comando
                bool ok = command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
                return Ok(ok);
            }
    }
```

De esta manera lo Ejecuto.

```
  Dim ListadoCxc As List(Of CuentaPorCobrar) = New List(Of CuentaPorCobrar)

    Dim Filtro = " Where pr.codempresa='" + JarSoft.Codempresa + "'  and pr.balance>0 "
    Dim datos = GetDatos(Filtro)'Retorna un Datatable
    For Each dr As DataRow In datos.Rows
        Dim itemcxc As CuentaPorCobrar = New CuentaPorCobrar
        itemcxc.Atraso = dr("Atraso") : itemcxc.Balance = dr("Balance") : itemcxc.Capital = dr("Capital")
        itemcxc.Cedula = dr("Cedula") : itemcxc.Cliente = dr("Cliente") : itemcxc.Codclte = dr("Codclte")
        itemcxc.Codcontrol = dr("Codcontrol") : itemcxc.Coddoc = dr("Coddoc") : itemcxc.Codempresa = dr("Codempresa")
        itemcxc.CodMod = dr("CodMod") : itemcxc.Codmoneda = dr("Codmoneda") : itemcxc.Codprestamo = dr("Codprestamo")
        itemcxc.Comentario = dr("Comentario") : itemcxc.Cuota = dr("Cuota") : itemcxc.DiasAtraso = dr("DiasAtraso")
        itemcxc.Direccion = dr("Direccion") : itemcxc.Divisa = dr("Divisa") : itemcxc.EsSolicitud = dr("EsSolicitud")
        itemcxc.Fecha = dr("Fecha") : itemcxc.FPago = dr("FPago") : itemcxc.FultimoPago = dr("FultimoPago")
        itemcxc.Garante = dr("Garante") : itemcxc.GaranteCedula = dr("GaranteCedula") : itemcxc.GaranteDireccion = dr("GaranteDireccion")
        itemcxc.GaranTetelefono = dr("GaranTetelefono") : itemcxc.IdReg = dr("IdReg")
        itemcxc.IdTransaccion = dr("IdTransaccion") : itemcxc.Interes = dr("Interes")
        itemcxc.Latitud = dr("Latitud") : itemcxc.LatitudPago = dr("LatitudPago") : itemcxc.Longitud = dr("Longitud")
        itemcxc.LongitudPago = dr("LongitudPago") : itemcxc.Modalidad = dr("Modalidad") : itemcxc.MontoAbono = dr("MontoAbono")
        itemcxc.Mora = dr("Mora") : itemcxc.MoraPagada = dr("MoraPagada") : itemcxc.Movil = dr("Movil")
        itemcxc.Numero = dr("Numero") : itemcxc.RefCodcontrol = dr("RefCodcontrol") : itemcxc.RefCodoc = dr("RefCodoc")
        itemcxc.RefCuota = dr("RefCuota") : itemcxc.Referencia = dr("Referencia") : itemcxc.RefFmov = dr("RefFmov")
        itemcxc.RefIdReg = dr("RefIdReg") : itemcxc.RefNumero = dr("RefNumero") : itemcxc.Telefono = dr("Telefono")
        itemcxc.Imagen = JarSoft.ImagenToBytes(JarSoft.ImagenFromFile(dr("Imagen")))
        itemcxc.Valor = dr("Valor")
        ListadoCxc.Add(itemcxc)
    Next

    Dim uri As System.Uri = New Uri("http://localhost:7710/")'Servicio Montado en IIS y Esta Corriendo.
    Dim Client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    Dim Deserialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListadoCxc)
    Client.BaseAddress = uri
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))

    Dim Respuesta As HttpResponseMessage = Await Client.PostAsync("api/SingCronizarcxc", New StringContent(Deserialized, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
```

Ayuda por Favor

Comment: El problema no es que estas agregando todos los parametros mas de una vez?? lo estas definiendo, le das valor, y despues lo volves a definir con un valor? probaste depurar esto?

Comment: Ya corregí la pregunta el otro código lo copié por error lo que pasa es que son 2 proyecto a parte y no lo puedo debuguear

Comment: @JOSEANGELRAMIREZHERNANDEZ ¿Son proyectos en diferente o en la solución?. Si usas Visual Studio tienes la opción de ejecutar múltiples proyectos. Podrías leer: [Cómo: Establecer múltiples proyectos de inicio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms165413.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), recuerda que haciendo click en "Otras versiones" te muestra para otras versiones de VS.

Answer (score 1):

Nos podrías facilitar la salida completa del error, yo creería que el error es porque el return Ok("lo que sea"); no siempre es alcanzable...

```
public IHttpActionResult Metodo(){
    try{
        /// Acá toda tu lógica
        return Ok("Cualquier cosa");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok voy a colocar la exención generada

Comment: tiene razon con algo.. no todas las rutas de codigo tienen un return. si el parametro viene vacio no hay nada que devolver. Esto compila?